# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 hung compiling Groovy code

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm experiencing a very strange problem when compiling a Groovy project with IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 (Mac OSX).

After I've annotated some groovy classes with @CompileStatic, as soon as I build the project the IntelliJ compiler hung on the "instruction selection" stage and starts consuming all CPUs resources (I can see the CPUs running above 700%).

The compilation never complete. Building using an external tool (Gradle) it compiles without any problem.

Any clue what cloud be the problem. Is the a workaround?

Comment: Looks like something to be reported to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard. Some thread dumps taken by jstack (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667) of GroovycRunner process might give a hint.

Comment: I've reported an issue for this http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing the latest IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2 RC build 135.689

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13.1+EAP